# Showing nearest franchise location with Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I want to give users the availability to provide a link to their business locations on their profile and if they have multiple locations it would show the visitor the nearest. (This is what I am trying to tackle with Google Maps, if possible.)

Can I share a link with Google Maps, that will request user for his location and show nearest franchise location of X company?

Example: User clicks link-> Location Request & Provided -> Show nearest X company location.

If not, is there a way to implement something similar, even if the map is integrated in the site?

Answer (score 1):

[BatchGeo](http://batchgeo.com) is a good place to start. You'll need to look at their Spreadsheet Template to make sure that you're importing all the information you'll need.  [The Store Locator](http://batchgeo.com/features/store-locator/) function is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3) is along the lines of what you're looking for.  You have to pre-add your store locations into a database, but essentially you can do it using php, MySQL and the Google Maps API to lets a user "enter their address and see markers on a map for the locations nearest to them".